# FileZilla and private key with passphrase

Tags: sftp

I know filezilla can work with pageant for private keys protected with a passphrase, however can you use fileszilla with a private key that is protected with a passphrase without using pageant? I am talking about Filezilla 3.26.2

Many thanks.

Comment: Please can you add more details about what you are trying to achieve. As it stands, I'm tempted to just say "no".

Comment: Also, does this help in any way? https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto